# SSRS How to hide the first five records

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can I hide the first five records in the tablix?

İ am using Top N filtering. I have two tablixes. The first one displays Top 5 records. The second one must display Top (6-10).

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the visibility of the row based on the [RowNumber](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function.

For example, set the visibility of the row to something like:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) >= 6 and RowNumber(Nothing) <= 10, false, true)
```

Should hide any rows other than 6-10.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is correct. It worked when i changed "or" to "and"..

Comment: Great! Sorry about the typo - glad you got it all going.